# Sending an email based on returned values from Joins table

Tags: android, mysql, email

I have resolved this issue but come across another, the select statements are now working but the email intent is not being run (well I'm not receiving any emails)

my create statement is now;

```
myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dressdetails " +
                "(dress_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, profile_id INTEGER, image1 BLOB, designer VARCHAR, style VARCHAR, size VARCHAR, viel VARCHAR, " +
                "drycleaning VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY(profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id));");
```

I have a clickable button which allow the user to go into their devices gallery and retrieve a photo

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });
}

// Method to receive bundle with image Uri and convert to bitmap so it can be inputted into the database
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    try{
        switch(requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
                    stream.toByteArray();
                }
        }
        // Catch input/output errors
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then attempt to insert the image

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO dressdetails(profile_id, designer, style, size, viel, drycleaning) VALUES ('" + idReceived + "', '" +
            yourSelectedImage + "', '" + Designer + "', '" + Style + "', '" + WhatSize + "', '" + WantViel + "', '" + DryCleaningCost + "');");
```

The next part is where I'm going wrong I think;

```
/// Method to convert the image from int to byte[] so can be stored in database ///


public byte[] convertToByteArray(int image){

    Resources resources = getResources();
    Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(image);
    Bitmap bitmap =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    //byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();
    return stream.toByteArray();
    //return bitmapData;

}


/// Sample dresses inputted for your purposes, now when you search there will be some dresses to output /// + yourSelectedImage + "', '"
public void inputExamples() {


    int image10 = R.drawable.wdone;
    int image2 = R.drawable.wdtwo;
    int image3 = R.drawable.wdthree;
    int image4 = R.drawable.wdfour;
    int image5 = R.drawable.wdfive;
    int image6 = R.drawable.wdsix;
    int image7 = R.drawable.wdseven;
    int image8 = R.drawable.wdeight;
    int image9 = R.drawable.wdnine;

    byte[] eg1 = convertToByteArray(image10);
    byte[] eg2 = convertToByteArray(image2);
    byte[] eg3 = convertToByteArray(image3);
    byte[] eg4 = convertToByteArray(image4);
    byte[] eg5 = convertToByteArray(image5);
    byte[] eg6 = convertToByteArray(image6);
    byte[] eg7 = convertToByteArray(image7);
    byte[] eg8 = convertToByteArray(image8);
    byte[] eg9 = convertToByteArray(image9);
```

I was direct to prepared statements which I looked at but if I'm honest I'm only new to this and it went a bit over my head.

I then have a select query on this joins table to retrieve the dress back along with other information which I want to then forward in an email.

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT profile_id, image1, designer, drycleaning FROM dressdetails INNER JOIN profile ON (" +
            "profile.id = dressdetails.profile_id) WHERE dressdetails.size LIKE '%" + size + "%' OR dressdetails.style LIKE '%" + style + "%' OR dressdetails.viel LIKE '%"
            + viel + "%';", null);*/
if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            // store it as a string in a variable
            dressesProfileId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("profile_id"));

            /// *** HERE is where I store the image into a variable *** ///
            //queryImageRetrieved = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image1"));
            dryCleaningDetails = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("drycleaning"));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
```

I convert string to byte[]

```
 /// *** Here I try to convert the string back into a byte array *** ///
    byte[] bytes;
    try{
        bytes = queryImageRetrieved.getBytes("UTF-8"); BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, queryImageRetrieved.length());
        // Catch any I/O exceptions
        System.out.println("You have reached here and bytes has a value " + bytes);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then another cursor to retrieve the contact info of the matching user

```
 /// method 2 for returning contact details of matching dress from profile table and storing in variables ///
    String rentorName = "";
    String rentorEmail = "";
    String rentalPrice = "";
    String query = "SELECT username, useremail, rentalprice FROM profile INNER JOIN dressdetails ON (" +
            "profile.id = dressdetails.profile_id) WHERE id = ?";
    Cursor c1 = myDB.rawQuery(query, new String[] { dressesProfileId });
    //Cursor c1 = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT username, useremail FROM profile INNER JOIN dressdetails ON (" +
            //"profile.id = dressdetails.profile_id) WHERE profile.id = ?", new String[] {dressesProfileId});
    if(c1.moveToFirst()) {
        // Store the values needed in variables so we can send it to the user in an email with the image
        do {
            rentorName = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("username"));
            rentorEmail = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("useremail"));
            rentalPrice = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("rentalprice"));
            sellerContactDetails = "The name of the seller is " + rentorName + ", their email address is " + rentorEmail +
                    ", the rental price is " + rentalPrice + " and the dry cleaning cost is " + dryCleaningDetails + ";";

            // Check that it has worked - Debug tool
            Toast.makeText(this, sellerContactDetails, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Continue until no more dresses match the set criteria
        } while (c1.moveToNext());
    }

    // Close the cursor and the database
    c1.close();
    myDB.close();
```

Finally I have the email intent to send the retrieved info&image to user.

```
// Send results to users email
    Log.i("Send email", "");

    String[] TO = { rentorEmail };
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");


    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "P2P Weddings");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sellerContactDetails);

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i("Finished sending email ", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(SearchCriteria.this,
                "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I know this is a long one sorry, I’m so close to finishing my first app but have been stuck at this point for a week! Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks guys!

This is what the logcat is saying

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[B@350f45fe, 'Versace', 'Off the shoulder', '6', 'Yes', '€25');" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dressdetails(profile_id, image1, designer, style, size, viel, drycleaning) VALUES (1, [B@350f45fe, 'Versace', 'Off the shoulder', '6', 'Yes', '€25');
```

Comment: what do you experience? Do you see the Chooser? What happens next?

Comment: I've just edited the post to show the logcat error message.  When I take the image column out of the table completely the app runs fine, it just doesn't like insert or retrieving images for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourSelectedImage is a Bitmap, and here you add yourSelectedImage.toString() to the table:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO dressdetails(profile_id, designer, style, size, viel, drycleaning) VALUES ('" + idReceived + "', '" +
            yourSelectedImage + "', '" + Designer + "', '" + Style + "', '" + WhatSize + "', '" + WantViel + "', '" + DryCleaningCost + "');");
```

I suggest not to save the image into the DB but if you do, you should serialize the Bitmap and make sure you escape it correctly as well.

update:

According to the error message you included in the question, the above SQL statement equals to this string:

```
"INSERT INTO dressdetails(profile_id, image1, designer, style, size,
viel, drycleaning) VALUES (1, [B@350f45fe, 'Versace', 'Off the shoulder',
'6', 'Yes', '€25');"
```

Do you see the "**[B@350f45fe**" ?

Something is clearly wrong here, because the 2nd parameter in VALUES should be enclosed in single quotes. I don't know how they disappeared, probably it's some overflow or even sql injection (or even if it's not an intentional injection if yourSelectedImage.toString() has single quotes, it renders an invalid SQL). But anyway, even if it worked it looks like you would've save the Bitmap.toString, which is something like 'Bitmap[@350f45fe]' but not the actual bitmap data.

Comment: Hey Gavriel, thanks for the response. That has worked for inserting the image from the device gallery.   I am also trying to insert some images from the drawable folder which is the convertToByteArray method above along with the inputExamples method but It is throwing the same error. Any idea why?